# Exporting data frames and graphs

Tags: r

I have a procedure that prints several data frames and graphs one after another. Is there some automated way to export them into a pdf document? Preferably the data frames would look like standard tables and the graphs would look the same.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like Sweave or knitr.

Comment: Which do you think would be easier to learn? I'm not doing anything complicated. I'm just turning the data frames into a table (with a title) and im keeping the graphs the same.
@HongOoi

Comment: Sweave comes with R, and if you're not terribly worried about the defaults, it'll do the job. You will have to install LaTeX though.

Comment: @HongOoi Is there absolutely no way to do it otherwise? I was hoping I could get it to run for anyone with an r download rather than them needing to download latex first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working example with knitr and R studio. First of all you can install knitr, you might also need to install MIKTEX on windows if you don't have Latex. Trust me this will get you long way if you want to do the analysis and plot your figures and tables at the same time.

Another thing you need to do is go to R studio and under options go to `Sweave` and change the settings for `Weaver` Rnw files using `Sweave or knitr` and then start with the code as follows. I have used the default data `iris` that comes with the R installation. You need to save your file with the extension `*.Rnw`.

THe minimum working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
# xtable library is added to export the table  
library(xtable)
@


<<figure,dpi=300,fig.cap="A sample graph from data (iris)",echo=FALSE,fig.height=6,fig.width=6,fig.pos='H',warning=FALSE,comment=NULL>>=
print(plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width))
@


I am going to print a sample dataframe in R using knitr and file format "*.Rnw".

<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
# You want to make sure you change results='asis' to show the table properly
print(xtable(head(iris),caption="This is a test graph"))
@

This a simple demonstration on how we can include figures and tables in a pdf document.

\end{document}
```

Finally, after installing everything and putting the code above you can hit `Compile PDF` in the R studio and then you pdf will be created.